# Is it a good idea to apply for PhD during my second Master degree?

Tags: phd

I graduated from M.sc in Applied Social psychology in 2017 (with thesis). And after a year of a research program in Poland, I decided to get an M.Sc in Clinical psychology (2-year program with thesis, I will graduate in 2021). I have been thinking whether it is possible to apply for Ph.D this year without delaying for another year until I complete my current program.

Could you please advise whether it can be done and whether it will look appropriate in my CV if I do so.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would it look bad? Do you mean to quit leave your current Master's halfway through?

Comment: Yes, if I quit will it look bad in my Ph.D. application and in CV?

Comment: Would you start this fall? In the US, it would be generally too late to start any earlier than fall 2021 anyway.

Comment: ¿ applied social psychology ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can justify why you pursued a second master degree at first and why you want to quit (if I well understood), then you will not look bad.

I know many people who worked in the industry after their master and then turned back to academia. They could explain why they want to do a PhD and were convincing.

If you are motivated and have good reasons to do a PhD instead of finishing the second master degree, then go for it. However, remember that any employer will ask about critical decisions in your professional life. Examples include: 1) why did you leave your last job? What motivates you to pursue a PhD? What motivated you to pursue a second master? etc.